# php orm with DB2 using PDO drivers (Pdo_odbc or pdo_ibm)

Tags: php, orm, db2

Wih doctrine, propel or any other php orm, can I use db2 with pdo drivers?

If there is no support directly, then can we write adapters for db2 for that orm framework to make it work?

Comment: It might be best to ask this on the mailing list dedicated to each orm framework.

Comment: Propel does not support DB2 right now, but you can write an adapter class. You may want to look at the [existing adapters](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/tree/master/runtime/lib/adapter) to see how (can't find direct documentation on how to do it).

Comment: Get the latest builds of Doctrine 2 (preferably using composer) to get DB2 support inherently. I have managed to implement a proof of concept for DB2 with Doctrine 2 ORM (there are some issues on the way but upto now they have been resolvable by editing the Doctrine2's DB2 related core files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) should support DB2 just fine out of the box.

Comment: Get the latest builds of Doctrine 2 (preferably using composer) to get DB2 support inherently. There will be some issues regarding unknown type mappings between DB2 types and Dcotrine2 types (most of them are mapped but some of them like vargraphic, graphic, blob, xml etc are not mapped) but can easily be mapped in the DB2Platform.php file or other means.